# Visual C++ LNK2005 error: variable-name already defined in filename.obj(Using SFML)

Tags: visual-c++, sfml

I have 3 files in my project, main.cpp, Globals.h & Globals.cpp:

#### main.cpp

```
#include "Globals.h"

int main()
{
if (setup())return 1;//If setup fails terminate the program
CenterOrigin(playerSprite);
while (window.isOpen())
    {
    deltaTime = deltaClock.restart().asSeconds();
    while (window.pollEvent(ev))
       {
        if (ev.type == sf::Event::Closed)window.close();
       }
    float rotSpeed = 5;

    window.clear(sf::Color(12, 14, 12, 0.9 * 255));

    window.display();
    }
return 0;
}
```

#### Globals.h

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>  
#include <SFML/System.hpp>

#define TITLE "Belty McBelth"
#define WIDTH 1280
#define HEIGHT 720

sf::RenderWindow window;
sf::Font font; 
sf::Event ev; 
sf::Texture playerTex; 
sf::Sprite playerSprite; 
sf::Texture tieTex; 
sf::Sprite tieSprite; 

sf::Clock deltaClock;
float deltaTime; //Time since last frame in seconds

int setup();
void CenterOrigin(sf::Sprite & t);
```

#### Globals.cpp

```
#include "Globals.h"

int setup()
{
    window.create(sf::VideoMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT), "Belty McBelth", sf::Style::Close);
    if (!font.loadFromFile("../comic.ttf"))return 1;
    if (!playerTex.loadFromFile("../PLAYER.png"))return 1;
    playerSprite = sf::Sprite(playerTex);
    std::cout << "Setup completed without errors \n";
    return 0;
}

void CenterOrigin(sf::Sprite & t)
{
    sf::FloatRect d = t.getLocalBounds();
    t.setOrigin(d.width / 2, d.height / 2);
}
```

Whenever I try to build this project, I get a plethora of LNK2005 errors, one for each variable that is **declared** in the globals header file. I have searched for a solution to this problem, however I am not able to find one. I have ensured that there are no definitions in the globals.h file, however, I am still unable to build the project.

This problem solves itself if I move all the definitions into the .h file, however, through the microsoft page for the lnk2005 error, I have found that this is only because there is only one file that includes the globals header file.

Sidenote, is there any better way of handling global variables/functions? Extern is an option, but it gets too cumbersome when you have a lot of global variables.

Comment: You *define* variables in the header file, not only declaring them. That means all [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) where the header file is included will have definitions of those variables. Use `extern` in the header file to *declare* the variables, and move the *definition* ("implementation") of the variables to a single source file.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude 
Thanks that worked.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: would you make an answer, so that the question author can accept it? Thanks.